# Difference between two columns with separated variables by ; in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R and while trying to make some exercises I got stuck in one of them. My data.frame is as follow:

`LanguageWorkedNow      LanguageNextYear
 Java; PHP              Java; C++; SQL 
 C;C++;JavaScript;      JavaScript; C; SQL`

And I need to know the variables which are in `LanguageNextYear` and are not in `LanguageWorkedNow`, to set a list with the different ones.

Sorry if the question is duplicated, I'm quite new here and tried to find it, but with no success.

Comment: Is that comparison made by row? Or you can group all values in a column together (as a vector) and then compare two vectors?

Comment: By row. Actually I need to know if there is any diffent variable in each row to plot a graph with the number of users who wants to change the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### base R

Idea: `mapply` `setdiff` on `strsplit`ted NextYear and WorkedNow, and then paste it using `collapse=";"`:

```
df$New <- with(df, {
  a <- mapply(setdiff, strsplit(NextYear, ";"), strsplit(WorkedNow, ";"), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
  sapply(a, paste, collapse=";")
})
# SIMPLIFY = FALSE is needed in a general case, it doesn't
# affect the output in the example case
# Or if you use Map instead of mapply, that is the default, so
# it could also be...

df$New <- with(df, 
  sapply(Map(setdiff, strsplit(NextYear, ";"), strsplit(WorkedNow, ";")), 
     paste, collapse=";"))
```

### data

```
df <- read.table(text = "WorkedNow      NextYear
                Java;PHP              Java;C++;SQL  
                C;C++;JavaScript      JavaScript;C;SQL
                ", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `purrr` package:

```
df = read.table(text = "
LanguageWorkedNow      LanguageNextYear
Java;PHP              Java;C++;SQL  
C;C++;JavaScript      JavaScript;C;SQL
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(purrr)

df$New = map2_chr(df$LanguageWorkedNow, 
                  df$LanguageNextYear, 
                  ~{x1 = unlist(strsplit(.x, split=";"))
                    x2 = unlist(strsplit(.y, split=";"))
                    paste0(x2[!x2%in%x1], collapse = ";")})

df

#   LanguageWorkedNow LanguageNextYear     New
# 1          Java;PHP     Java;C++;SQL C++;SQL
# 2  C;C++;JavaScript JavaScript;C;SQL     SQL
```

For each row you get your columns and you create vectors of values (separated by `;`). Then you check which values of `NextYear` vector don't exist in `WorkedNow` vector and you create a string based on / combining those values.

The `map` function family will help you apply your logic / function to each row. In our case we use `map2_chr` as we have two inputs (your two columns) and we excpet a string / character output.